# Google Sheets - reading values with 'com.'

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to loop through a column of a Google sheet and apply some formatting. 
The data in column 2 looks like this:

```
name='com.android.dreams.basic'

name='com.android.bluetooth'

name='com.android.browser'

name='com.android.calculator2'

name='com.android.calendar'

name='com.android.camera2'
```

etc

For whatever reason, the data actually populating the "cell" variable is always "name='(class)'". I'm unsure why this isn't being read as the string that is actually in the cell. If "com.anything" is in the cell it will return '(class)'.

Thoughts? Below is my formatting function.

```js
function ApplyFormatting() {
  var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  // Get the entire sheet range  
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()
  
  for(var n = 0; n < values[0][0].length; n++){    
  var cell = values[n][2]
    if (cell == "name='com.android.bluetooth'") {
      currentSheet.GetRange(n +1, 1, 1, 1).setBagkgroundColor('green')
    }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: instead of `getValues` you can use get `getDisplayValues`. That should take care of forcing the cell value to be taken as a string. Also your loop should be `if(var n= 0; n<values.length;n++)`. Hope that helps.

Comment: I attempted it  - it returns the same '(class)'. Thanks for the heads up on the loop. I had not gotten that far yet :)

Comment: Interesting, when I copy paste the above data and run the code.. it doesn't seem to have that problem!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is only an artifact of the debugger in google-apps-script. The actual values are correct even though the debugger shows incorrect values.

Thanks for your help Jack!